# Laravel : Bootstrap-datepicker-sandbox highlight specific date

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

On a landing page a datepicker is loaded as you can see in the image. I want to be able to change the background colors of specific dates on the calendar.

For example :
If `27-11-2017` slot is booked, then on load I want the color to change for that date.

[image]

My Script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // I am getting a data on this loop so how can i change same date background color      
    @if(!empty($BookeData))
        @foreach($BookeData as $key => $value)
            @if($value->event_date)

            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
    /* Gt data in $BookeData
    array:13 [
    "id" => 8
    "source_type" => "App\Venue"
    "source_id" => 7
    "event_date" => "2017-11-28"
    "session" => "1"
    "payment" => "5000"
    "status" => "Booked"
    "created_at" => "2017-11-27 10:30:22"
    "updated_at" => "2017-11-27 10:30:22"
  ]*/

    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        multidate :true,
        maxViewMode: 0,
        startDate: today
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        var $date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', e.date);
        $("#event_date").val($date);
        //e.preventDefault();
        //var formData = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ route('admin.calendar.add') }}",
            data: {'date':$date},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                $("#calendar div.divForm").html(response);
                $("<input type='hidden' value='' name='event_date' id='event_date' />").appendTo('#calendar div.dateDiv');
                $("#event_date").val($date);
                $("#calendar").show();
            }
        });
    });

    $(".close").on("click", function() {
        $("#calendar").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `$value->event_date` gives you a booked date for a venue??

Comment: yes. you can check on array data..I want to change background color of the same date.

Comment: Ok, can you please add html code for the calendar also?

Comment: link : https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Just try: `$('#whateverID').datetimepicker({
                color: yellow;background: white;
            }
        });`

Comment: And how can i ,atch date ?? my  $value->event_date and calendar date ?

Comment: Try to add this in your `@if` statement as you told it's give you a date!

Comment: $value->event_date give me a 27-11-2017 date, now on calendar i want to highlight same date so first i want to find out same date on calendar after that apply css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand your issue, try as like below:

`<input type="text" id="datepicker" />`

```
var booked_date = ["27/11/2017"];  //Take your booked date here from your data

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
 format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true,
 beforeShowDay: function(date){
     var d = date;
     var curr_date = d.getDate();
     var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
     var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
     var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

     if ($.inArray(formattedDate, booked_date) != -1){
       return {
          classes: 'activeClass'
       };
     }
  return;
 }
});
```

The `activeClass` can be any form of CSS. In my example i have just changed the background color. In your example you could offset an image and apply it to the day.

```
.activeClass{
   color: yellow;
   background: white; 
}
```

Hope this helps you OR you can get some idea!

Comment: Glad i could help you brother! Happy coding :) ^_^ Try to change css according you want!

Comment: one more question if i want to loop this script as i told you that i am getting only one date at loop $value->event_date .how can i set my code.

Comment: `var booked_date = ["27/11/2017"];` is an `array();`. So you can take many dates which comes from your data! I mean your dates from loop and set it there!

Comment: But there is a date on my loop and a flag for the full day and half day booking..so i want to test condition if same day date & flag== full day then apply some css..